# Sonarqube:Java is not catching "Double-checked Locking" (S2168)

Tags: java, sonarqube, double-checked-locking

We've started running our code through Fortify, and as an exercise I wanted to see if Sonarqube would pick up any of the same issues.

One of the first ones I'm unable to replicate is [S2168:Double-Checked Locking](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/tag/multi-threading/RSPEC-2168)

The guilty code fragment:

```
if (instance == null)
    {
        // thread safe singleton
        synchronized (ESSingletonClient.class)
        {
            if (instance == null) // doubly check
            {
               ...stuff
            }
        }
    }
```

I was running this on the default quality profile, Sonar Way, which appears to have this in its list.  For grins I created a new profile based off "Sonar Way", and then added everything from "Findbugs Security Audit", but that's not finding the code segment, either.

Any thoughts on what I may be missing?

clean install:
 - Docker: sonarqube:alpine (7.0)

**UPDATE (4/11/18)**:

I created a simple class with only 2 methods.  They're identical to the original code, except one uses the volatile and the other doesn't.  I ran it through SQ, and neither method is flagged for a double check. 
-  SonarJava: 5.2 (build 13398)

**UPDATE (4/12/18)**:

Added assignment to variables, calling another method, as is done in our original code.  Still not being flagged.

```
/** volatile instance. */
private static volatile Integer v_instance = null;
/** non-volatile instance. */
private static Integer n_instance = null;

public static void getVolatileInstance() 
{
    if (v_instance == null)
    {
        // thread safe singleton
        synchronized (DoubleCheck.class)
        {
            if (v_instance == null) // doubly check
            {
                assignVolatile(5);
            }
        }
    }
}
public static void getNonVolatileInstance() 
{
    if (n_instance == null)
    {
        // thread safe singleton
        synchronized (DoubleCheck.class)
        {
            if (n_instance == null) // doubly check
            {
               assignNonVolatile(6);
            }
        }
    }
}    

public static void assignVolatile(Integer value)
{
    v_instance = value;
}

public static void assignNonVolatile(Integer value)
{
    n_instance = value;
}
```

Comment: Is `instance` declared as volatile?

Comment: private static volatile

Comment: I'd guess that SonarQube's just being smarter about it then; while it's rarely a good idea to do DCL, this appears to be a valid use of it.

Comment: Are you suggesting if I ran the same code through, but without volatile, that it would be picked up?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised.

Comment: sadly, no such luck.  it's still not being flagged.

Comment: SonarQube and Fority are two different products with different goals. See also [this](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/LCK10-J.+Use+a+correct+form+of+the+double-checked+locking+idiom) discussion.

Comment: yes, they are.  But this is a case where they both happen to support catching the same feature.  And it's being caught in one, but not the other.

Comment: I checked it and SonarQube 7.0 with SonarJava 5.2 finds double-checked locking problem when instance variable has signature `private static Type instance` (without `volatile`). Could you add a class for which the issue in not reported (you can write a new one if your current class is secret ;-) ). It will allow to verify that you didn't hit a FP.

Comment: @agabrys I've updated my original post.

Comment: Please change `System.out.println("stuff");` to assignment operation and verify again. You should get one issue (for variable which is not `volatile`)

Comment: @agabrys Thank you for your participation.  I made the recommended changes, updated OP, and still nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You hit a False <s>Positive</s> Negative ([@benzonico](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1263543/) rightly pointed out that it is not a False Positive but False Negative). I sent an email with detailed information to SonarQube distribution list (https://groups.google.com/d/topic/sonarqube/1UXBR9eZydU/discussion):

> Hello,
>
> Adam L hit a false positive in the S2168 rule when an instance is assigned in an other method. He added a post on Stack Overflow [Sonarqube:Java is not catching "Double-checked Locking" (S2168)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49741933/4944847) (I apologize for cross-posting) and today I finally confirmed that the problem is caused by the rule.
>
> Environment:
>
> - SonarQube 7.0
> - SonarJava 5.2
>
> Example class:
>   https://github.com/agabrys/sonarqube-falsepositives/blob/master/src/main/java/biz/gabrys/agabrys/sonarqube/falsepositives/d20180415/S2168.java
>
> Project:
>   https://github.com/agabrys/sonarqube-falsepositives
>
> Build:
>   mvn clean package sonar
>
> Regards

Now we have to wait for an answer with two possibilities:

- a ticket to handle it will be created
- they will decide to not fix it

---

#### Edit:

I upgraded SonarJava from 5.2 to 5.5 and the issue is marked as fixed.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and participation in finding a resolution !!

Comment: Quick note : this is a false _negative_ (issue there but not found).